# How to convert a string with literal hex to hex?

Tags: python, string, hex

I'm writing a GUI to build transaction messages to a payment processing platform. You put what you want in each field and it builds the message in ascii hex. I have a text widget that displays the hex as a string so you can edit it. Example for 12 dollars is below:

`303030303030303031323030`

now, when I send it to the processor I have to encode it. This makes it convert what is already ascii hex, into ascii hex again...

`333033303330333033303330333033303331333233303330`

The hex is stored in a string variable so it can be displayed and edited from the GUI's text widget. I need to convert it to hex for socket send, without re-encoding it to ascii. Any ideas?

Comment: decode hex ascii is trivial `bytes.fromhex('303030303030303031323030')`, but send it via socket is another thing, you have to choose how to encode it as binary and separate between other value.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html